# How to modify Azure Devops email notification template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How to modify the build notification template in Azure Devops.

Need to add some details in the notification body.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There currently is no way to update the notification template. If you want more power over the emails being generated, you can link [Microsoft Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=azure%20devops) or IFTTT to the servicehooks and send custom email templates from there.

I also recommend you submit a feature request to the [Azure DevOps Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html), not just for the ability to change the templates, but to voice what data you're currently missing and why that data is important.

Comment: There is a feature request already https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365760/customise-vsts-email-templates.html so feel free to vote for it or comment.