# How to add info to default Azure DevOps Notification?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

With help of Levi Lu-MSFT, I created a pipeline in which I can compare the total execution time of the gatling load scenario (it is stored in another pipeline) last time with the previous time. Here is the ps script for it:

```
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"
echo $url

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

# calculate the totaltime of the newest build
$time = [datetime]$result.finishTime - [datetime]$result.startTime

$thisBuild= $time.TotalMinutes

# get the last build
$lasturl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId)&resultFilter=succeeded&`$top=2&api-version=5.1"

$lastResult =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $lasturl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

#Caculate the totaltime of the last build
$lasttime = [datetime]$lastResult.value[1].finishTime - [datetime]$lastResult.value[1].startTime
$lastBuild = $lasttime.TotalMinutes

#Store the result to varialbe  isLonger    
if($thisBuild -ge $lastBuild ){ echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isLonger]True" }
```

How can I put values of $thisBuild & $lastBuild in the body of default Azure DevOps e-mail notification?

Comment: What leads you to believe that you **can** do that?

Comment: I don't want to use such tasks in pipeline as "SendMail" or "SendGrid". That's why I want to realize. how to add info in default Azure notification.

Comment: afaik, you cannot do that, but you can follow below link to get additional info about how to accomplish it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632159/how-to-modify-azure-devops-email-notification-template

Comment: Thank you, Mario! Your advice is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

> How to add info to default Azure DevOps Notification?

As of today, we does not open customized operation of **default Azure DevOps Notification**  to users. The structure of mail content is fixed by our system. That's why Daniel and Mario said that is impossible to achieve.

What the great is, there has many users interested with this feature. And our team has take this [suggestion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365760/customise-vsts-email-templates.html) into consideration. You can vote and keep that suggestion followed, so that you will receive the update in time.

---

As a work around, you can consider the suggestion that Mario mentioned. It just need you configure the flow and the fields you needed.

Another work around is using powershell to send mail through SMTP server by using **powershell script**:

```
$emailSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$emailSmtpServerPort = "587"
$emailSmtpUser = "liangxxxx@gmail.com"
$emailSmtpPass = "xxxxx"

$emailFrom = "xxxxx@gmail.com"
$emailTo = "xxxxx@outlook.com" 
$emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $emailFrom , $emailTo )
$emailMessage.Subject = "subject" 
#$emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true #true or false depends
$emailMessage.Body = "{the custom body you want to have}"

$SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort )
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
$SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage )
```

---

But I would suggest you using **microsoft flow** to achieve what you want. Because send mail through script need you enable lower secure app access for the sender account. Or you will receive the error like `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated.`

Comment: Thank you, Merlin! Your advice is very helpful!

Comment: @Artsiom. It's welcome. Just the work arounds are much complexed to achieve. Anyway, awesome to know they are help. You can accept it if you think it would also help others who has similar expectation with you:-)